# Differences between Numpy divide and Python divide?

Tags: python, numpy, division, elementwise-operations

What are the similarities and differences between **numpy.divide** and the Python slash **/** operator? As far as I can tell they behave the same, both implementing an element-wise division. The [Numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html) mentions:

> numpy.divide(x1, x2) ... Equivalent to x1 / x2 in terms of array-broadcasting. ...

Implying that np.divide(x1, x2) is not **completely** equivalent to x1 / x2.
I have run the following snippet to compare their speed:

```
import numpy as np
import time

a = np.random.rand(10000, 10000)
b = np.random.rand(10000, 10000)

tic = time.time()
c = a / b
toc = time.time()
print("Python divide took: ", toc - tic)

tic = time.time()
c = np.divide(a, b)
toc = time.time()
print("Numpy divide took: ", toc - tic)
```

It appears that the Python divide generally runs faster which leads me to believe the Numpy divide implements some additional bells and whistles.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This seems to be purely an artifact of not benchmarking things properly. If I use `timeit`, I get 540ms for `a/b`, and 539ms for `np.divide(a, b)`. And if I use your naive benchmarking, whichever one I do first takes longer.

Comment: Yes. Clearly, one of the results are cached by your CPU.

Comment: Or maybe it's just the allocation—the first one needs to malloc space for the array; the second one reuses the just-freed space. But I'll dig up the source to make sure they're the same.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any actual performance difference here.

When I run your code, and swap the two tests, whichever one comes second goes faster.

When I use `timeit` for proper benchmarking, they take about the same time (540ms for `/` vs. 539ms for `divide`).

My guess would be that the difference you measured was the time to malloc the array—the first one needs to do that, the second one can reuse the memory that just got freed.

---

But let's look at the source. The code in [`generate_umath.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/code_generators/generate_umath.py#L297) creates the actual code, and it's assigning the same `Ufunc` (named `numpy.core.umath.divide`) to `np.floor_divide` and to the `PyNumber_FloorDivide` slot for `np.ndarray`. (If you're wondering why I looked up `floor_divide` when you're using `divide` and `/` instead of `floor_divide` and `//`, see the comment later where it deletes `divide` for Python 3 because it will be aliased it to `true_divide`.) IIRC, the actual code is a switch on types and sizes that ultimately ends up in one of the loop templates in [`loops.c.src`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c.src#L2547).

So, beyond the differences in explicit Ufunc wrapper code vs. builtin `method-wrapper` wrapper code (which is going to be irrelevant for any array that isn't tiny), they end up in the same place.