# Numpy np.multiply vs *-Operator

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any difference in using

```
import numpy as np

a, b = np.random([1024, 1024]), np.random([1024, 1024])
c = np.multiply(a, b)
```

over

```
c = a * b
```

or is the `*`-Operator on numpy-arrays simply overridden with `np.multiply`?

---

***Edit***: This question is marked as duplicate because [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49459661/differences-between-numpy-divide-and-python-divide) asks the same thing about the division operator (`np.divide()` vs `/`) and similar answers followed, but unless it is changed to "numpy arithmetic vs. python arithmetic" or something of the kind, it won't help people wondering the same thing as I did (about multiplication) and not being "clever" enough to assume a question about a related arithmetic operation (division) generalizes to all the basic arithmetic operations. To [make it easier finding answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/), I'd advocate for keeping this question as is.

Comment: I did look at the docs and looked around on SO. If you are referring to the docs, I found `Equivalent to x1 * x2 in terms of array broadcasting.` not to be an answer to this question, as it explicitly says it is equivalent "... in terms of broadcasting", leaving me wondering whether there are other differences, e.g. in terms of speed.

Comment: Snarky comment, and this question being closed as dupe, is why SO is broken and subject of ridicule at r/ProgrammerHumor. That this question came up first when I googled `numpy multiply vs *` shows the  system is still working despite itself

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no difference. However, the `np.multiply` function can take in additional, optional arguments, making it more versatile. See the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html).

Saying that `*` is overwritten with `np.multiply` would not be very precise. Generally, `*` maps to calls to the `__mul__` and `__rmul__` methods on the objects on which it acts. Thus, `*` is rather "overwritten" with `np.ndarray.__mul__`.

Comment: One interesting to note too, is that np.multiply can be used for non numpy arrays: `[ x1, ..., xn ] * [y1, ..., yn]` wouldn't work, but `np.multiply([ x1, ..., xn ] * [y1, ..., yn])` does.

Answer (score 11):

speed differences - none:

```
In [65]: timeit c = np.multiply(a,b)
4.95 ms ± 10.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [66]: timeit c = a*b
5.06 ms ± 180 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

For smaller arrays we might see differences due to a different calling stack, but with these, the actual computation dominates the time.

But as you can see from the docs, `np.multiply` is a `ufunc` with access to all the machinery that that implies.

For `np.matrix` objects, `*` is matrix product, `np.multiply` is element multiplication.

Comment: We need more people like you @hpaulj. Benchmarking is the ultimate proof!