# Is numpy.multiply always equivalent to the * operator?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication, vector-multiplication

The [numpy.multiply documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) says:

> Equivalent to x1 * x2 in terms of array broadcasting.

Is `np.multiply(x1, x2)` different to `x1 * x2` in any circumstance?

Where would I find the implementations of each?

---

Note: An [analogous question exists for division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49459661/differences-between-numpy-divide-and-python-divide) but it doesn't mention multiplication, nor imply that the the answer would be the same in the multiplicative case.

This question also asks for implementation details specific to multiplication.

Comment: Samething was asked 3 days ago: [Numpy np.multiply vs *-Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49493482/numpy-np-multiply-vs-operator)

Comment: Why are you asking?  Do you have some odd-ball circumstance that you wondering about?  What kinds of objects are you using?  The `equivalent` statement applies to numeric `ndarray`, not `np.matrix` or `list`.

Comment: It's very weird that we suddenly get three (maybe more) near-identical questions in under a week, when I only ever remember seeing one of them before (and can't find it in a search). Is someone teaching a new course full of experienced programmers but who are new to numpy or something?

Comment: @abarnet I'm doing a coursera course but it's certainly not new. I'm just doing a deep dive :)

Answer (score 7):

Supplementing @COLDSPEED's answer I'd like to stress that for non array operands results can actually be quite different:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> 2 * [1, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 2]
>>> np.multiply(2, [1, 2])
array([2, 4])
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `np.multiply` and the multiplication operator `*` work consistently for `ndarray` objects.

```
In [560]: x = np.array([1, 2, 3])

In [561]: y = np.array([4, 5, 6])

In [562]: x * y
Out[562]: array([ 4, 10, 18])

In [563]: np.multiply(x, y)
Out[563]: array([ 4, 10, 18])
```

The only major difference is in terms of `matrix` objects, for which, the `*` is setup to perform matrix multiplication (i.e., the dot product).

```
In [564]: x, y = map(np.matrix, (x, y))

In [565]: np.multiply(x, y)
Out[565]: matrix([[ 4, 10, 18]])

In [566]: x * y
ValueError: shapes (1,3) and (1,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Also, as @PaulPanzer mentioned in his answer, they behave differently when multiplying pure-python lists with scalars.

Comment: Where would I get access to the implementation of these? I was hoping for a link from the documentation page...

Comment: @TomHale You can peruse the matrix code here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/9a4b692cb723b1eefea52ac6d5f1c6e2f6ed3187/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py#L306 As for the array multiplication code, you may look at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src#L247 but that's in C.